# i need to know what different between screen size and screen density

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, screen

in my android app i need to support multiple  screens (all sizes and all screens )
so i have read about density and screen size but i don't know what i should to choose when i creat another xml file for every single activity .. a four xml files depend on screen size like this :

```
res/layout/your_layout.xml             (layout for normal screen)
res/layout-small/your_layout.xml       (layout for small screen)
res/layout-large/your_layout.xml       (layout for large screen)
res/layout-xlarge/your_layout.xml      (layout for extra large screen)
```

or five files to support all density like what i do with drawable png files
plz help me to find the answer i need to what better and what the deference between them .

Answer (score 0):

This is so simple like if you are using hard values like `setText="22sp`.Now it might good your test mobile but good for every mobile screen so you have to create four folder

```
**hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi**
```

Copy the same file in these 4 folders and adjust it. when the app runs on any mobile Android framework automatically detects the screen and gets one of them.

Note: if you are using not hard values like `matchparent` etc then no need to create 4 duplicate files of that.

Comment: i understand that but i need to know which better to use screen size or density when i creat four xml files